# Adding color bar to 4D graph

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I add a color bar to my graph?

```
xyz = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 10, .35}, {j, 1, 10, .35}, {k, 1, 10, .35}], 2];

f[x_, y_, z_] :=  (1 + z) + Im[Sqrt[-( (z))^2 - x z]]

Graphics3D[Point[xyz, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[f[##] & @@@ xyz])], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first define another colorfunction

```
cf := If[# > 0, Hue[#/200], Black] &
```

then I would use `ListPointPlot3D`

```
 ListPointPlot3D[xyz, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, cf@f[x, y, z]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {-100, 200}}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: your colorbar doesn't show values of the function correctly

Comment: Ok, but I can not choose your answer because it is not complete

Comment: I didnt find it

Comment: BarLegend doesnt have such a option

Comment: Is there any option which can show negative parts of the graph in forexample black?

Comment: you could replace your `Hue` with `If[# > 0, Hue[#], Black] &`.

Comment: see edited code

Comment: The code you post (removing the `AxesLabel`) actually works for my machine

Comment: `cf := If[# < 0, Hue[#/3], Black] & ; ListPointPlot3D[xyz, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, cf@f[x, y, z]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {-3, 3}}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`